# Changing old UI on Xcode to new UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is a newbie question. But I would like to change my old UI (pngs) on my current project to some new updated ones that are of similar size. Is there anyway to drag and drop the UI directly without affecting the actions so the buttons still work the same on the app. Or do you have to recode everything when you change UI? I'm not really sure the steps I need to do, but I have all the new UI ready to go. Can anybody guide me through these steps?

Another question is, I have a video editor and want to test out a video player in the simulator at run time, but right now I can see my music or video files because I don't have any in the simulator. How do I import these files into a project to test it out (on the computer), I know the camera roll on a phone would work.

If anybody can give me some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it. I know these are newbie questions.

Thanks,

Comment: Just replace old pngs with new pngs with same name?

Comment: If you have images that you want to replace, just replace them in Finder.

Comment: How do I go about doing this? @BaSha

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the camera roll to display a video on the computer?

Comment: @rebello95 how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new images are the same size of the old images, just rename the new images exactly like the old images and then overwrite the old images at the project's path.

And for the video files, drag the video files directly to the iOS simulator. The video will open in the Safari, click the share button in the tab bar of the safari and hit "Save Video".

Comment: How do I import the images into Xcode put the new image in it's place?

Comment: If the images have the same name, you don't have to import it. Just go to the project location and overwrite the images. The XCode will automatically load the new images.

Comment: Can someone guide me once I make a new group class with pngs. Does an image have to be the exact same size to drag and drop into the UI interface? Do I have to resize images before I can do this?